# Can golang protocol buffers with gRPC be cross compiled and used on different OS platforms?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

This question is specifically about compiling and using golang protocol buffers (with gRPC) on different OS platforms and I haven't seen any like it. Is it possible to compile a .proto file on Windows, and then use the generated file on Linux? Or vice versa?

I compiled the same .proto file on both Windows and Linux and diff showed different results. One difference is that the Windows compiled version sometimes repeats json in fields of request structs like this: `` Field1Name *type`protobuf ,bytes,1,opt,name=my_name,json=myName" json:"my_name,omitempty"` `` whereas the Linux version is: `` Field1Name *type`protobuf ,bytes,1,opt,name=my_name" json:"my_name,omitempty"` ``. This happens a lot, sometimes all the fields have this issue, sometimes only some of them, and sometimes none of them for a given request struct.

The other difference is that the fileDescriptor at the bottom is completely different for the two versions. The Windows version is longer by about 40 lines.

Comment: Have you tried it? If so, what issue(s) did you encounter?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it and it appears to be working but I can't test every possible case. Is this practice allowed/acceptable? Since go is cross-platform and the generated file is a .go file it seems odd/bad that the files are different.

Comment: I agree that it's strange. If you're using the same version of the same Go-based tool to compile the proto, you should get the same output. I would double-check that both are identical versions.

Comment: Good call. I just downloaded the latest version on both machines a couple days ago before noticing this but it turns out there was a duplicate, lower version `protoc` on an earlier part of my $PATH than the new version. Re-ran test with the same version `protoc` and both files were the same. It appears the answer to my question is yes. If you give an answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Reposted my comment as an answer.

Comment: Aside from that: why not simply use `GOOS=windows` on Linux or vice versa to cross compile?

Comment: Interesting idea but why when we don't need to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the same version of the same Go-based tool to compile the proto, you should get the same output. I would double-check that both are identical versions.